# XML elements to list XML objects

Tags: xml, r

How could I split the XML tree to a list of XML objects and then I like to user the function getNodeSet but the return value should include the root object "part"?

```
require(XML)

txt = "<doc>
         <part>
           <name>ABC</name>
           <type>XYZ</type>
           <cost>3.54</cost>
           <status>available</status>
         </part>
         <part>
           <name>ABC</name>
           <type>XYZ</type>
           <cost>3.54</cost>
           <status>available</status>
         </part>
       </doc>"

doc <- xmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
special_nodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "/*/part//*")
```

Comment: For the first question I found `xpathApply(doc, "//doc/*")` but this is not exactly what I am looking for because I dont want to specify the root doc. I want that it founds the tags part under each root.

Comment: And now I sorted out `getNodeSet(doc, "//part")`

Answer (score 1):

I think the nodes returned by `getNodeSet` are pointers into the underlying XML object, so for instance

```
> special_nodes[[1]]
<name>ABC</name> 
> xpathSApply(special_nodes[[1]], "../cost")
[[1]]
<cost>3.54</cost>
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get you, but `hasSentence = xpathApply(doc, "../part")` gives me not a list of xml objects where each entry is a xml tree of the form `<part>
           <name>ABC</name>
           <type>XYZ</type>
           <cost>3.54</cost>
           <status>available</status>
         </part>`

Comment: But `xpathSApply(special_nodes[[1]], "../../part")` does? Actually I'm not following why 'doc' appears in relation to my answer, which operates on `special_nodes[[1]]`; maybe you found the answer to your original question in some other way.

Comment: know my second problem is still alive, it depends on the question how to transform the result of `l<-getNodeSet(doc, "//part")` for each entry in l to a list of nodes. Taht means I want all nodes for i>0 in l[i] in a list where each entry is a node.